# How can i get MongoDB error after installing

Tags: mongodb

I have just instaled mongodb using brew. Trying to connect to the port 27017 and i am getting the following error:

```
2019-05-07T18:02:05.630+0200 I CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2019-05-07T18:02:05.644+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=75196 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Andreis-MacBook-Pro.local
2019-05-07T18:02:05.644+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.0.9
2019-05-07T18:02:05.644+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: fc525e2d9b0e4bceff5c2201457e564362909765
2019-05-07T18:02:05.644+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2019-05-07T18:02:05.644+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2019-05-07T18:02:05.644+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2019-05-07T18:02:05.644+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2019-05-07T18:02:05.644+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2019-05-07T18:02:05.645+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2019-05-07T18:02:05.645+0200 I STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
2019-05-07T18:02:05.645+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2019-05-07T18:02:05.645+0200 I NETWORK  [initandlisten] removing socket file: /tmp/mongodb-27017.sock
2019-05-07T18:02:05.645+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2019-05-07T18:02:05.645+0200 I CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I have uninstalled and installed mongo, not helping:(
I have tried to change the port to 27018, not helping:(
I am trying to make the directory as root, not working:(

```
Andreis-MacBook-Pro:~ Andrei$ > sudo chown -R $USER /data/db
chown: /data/db: Operation not permitted
Andreis-MacBook-Pro:~ Andrei$ > sudo chmod -R go+w /data/db
chmod: Unable to change file mode on /data/db: Operation not permitted
Andreis-MacBook-Pro:~ Andrei$
```

Answer (score 0):

The installation fails on account of the fact you do not have write access to the folder **data/db**

```
Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: /data/db, terminating
```

Comment: Can you explain how to fix this?

Comment: you need administrator name and password to Enable Root User in menu bar in Directory Utility . Install  as root ( with root user enabled ) . That is it but don't forget to diable root when you are done .

Comment: So i have enabled the root user and i am getting the same error?

Comment: I have fixed it:)